# url detection discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
    urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+',message.content.lower())
    if urls and message.channel.id == "702468264361590828":
        await message.channel.send("Links are not allowed in here")
```

This is our discord.py bot's code, the command you guys see on top is supposed to detect if a link is sent and then send a message afterwards. But it doesn't detect it. I've put `print` instead of `await message.channel.send("Links are not allowed in here")` but that didn't work either. I have everything imported. FYI I used this to import `re`:

```
pip install regex
```

I couldn't find a package named `re` so I used this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't need to import any packages. The re package (regex) comes with Python 3 already imported.

Your issue is caused by having a string version of the channel id. Channel ids are **always** in int form. So just remove the quotes around `"702468264361590828"`